# Не работает функция Char()

Tags: mysql, кодировка, char

При вводе команды:

`SELECT CHAR(128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137);`

Вместо Сйёаааадёё возвращает null

Хотя и тут на странице буквы не те что в книге изображены - там изображены буквы с диакритическими знаками. В чем может быть проблема?

Использовал using utf8mb4, но он работает только до 127 символа. А после возвращает ?.

Comment: *Вместо Сйёаааадёё возвращает null* Во-первых, `SELECT HEX(CHAR(128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137));` покажет, что возвращается ни разу не NULL. Во-вторых, с чего ты решил что должно вернуться `'Сйёаааадёё'`?

Comment: Если использовать ваш код, то возвращает " 80818283848586878889". Если убрать "hex", то вернет вопросики (которые сюда не вставляются).

В краце. В книге дают пример,  CHAR(128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137), который должен возвращать диакритические знаки (типа польские с закорючками сверху). У меня же вместо них вопросительные знаки. Я так понимаю это одна из тех "ошибок" в книгах которые проще пропустить, чем искать решение несколько дней. Так как приколы с кодировкой там нормально не разбирают.

Comment: *В книге дают пример, CHAR(128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137), который должен возвращать диакритические знаки (типа польские с закорючками сверху). У меня же вместо них вопросительные знаки.* То, что будет отображаться, зависит от кодировок - соединения и клиента.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что книга написана на каком то таком языке, который перевели, но данный пример остался без проверки и из за этого такие приколы могут быть?

Comment: А при переводе никто вообще ничего не проверяет, как правило. Вот оно переводчику надо? за правильность материала пусть автор отвечает, а он, переводчик, отвечает только за корректность перевода. Не, бывают случаи, когда переводом спецы занимаются - но обычно результат их перевода не в печать идёт... чё хоть за книга-то?

Comment: Оно понятно что инглиш надо осваивать. Но типо хотелось бы так сказать 'базу' на русском почитать.

Название книги "Алан Болье: Изучаем SQL. Генерация, выборка и обработка данных"